# Remove filling from circle

Tags: python

I need to remove the filling of a circle and I got stucked with my code.

My code:

```
def makeOutline(lines):
    delList = []
    for i in range(len(lines)-1):

        for j in range(len(lines)-1):
            if lines[i][j] == "X" and lines[i+1][j] != "-" and lines[i-1][j] != "-" and lines[i][j+1] != "-" and lines[i][j-1] != "-":
                delList.append((i,j))
        for elm in delList:
            i = elm[0]
            j = elm[1]
            lines[i]= lines[i][:j] + "-" + lines[i][j+1:]
```

This is the circle, it's an array with strings

```
-----------------------------------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
----------------XXXXXXXXX----------------
----------------XXXXXXXXX----------------
---------------XXXXXXXXXXX---------------
---------------XXXXXXXXXXX---------------
---------------XXXXXXXXXXX---------------
---------------XXXXXXXXXXX---------------
---------------XXXXXXXXXXX---------------
----------------XXXXXXXXX----------------
----------------XXXXXXXXX----------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
-----------------------------------------
```

And this is should be the result:

```
-----------------------------------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
----------------XX-----XX----------------
----------------X-------X----------------
---------------X---------X---------------
---------------X---------X---------------
---------------X---------X---------------
---------------X---------X---------------
---------------X---------X---------------
----------------X-------X----------------
----------------XX-----XX----------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
-----------------------------------------
```

However this is what I get with my code:

```
-----------------------------------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
----------------XX-----XX----------------
----------------X-XXXXX-X----------------
---------------X-X-----X-X---------------
---------------XX-XXXXX-XX---------------
---------------X-X-----X-X---------------
---------------XX-XXXXX-XX---------------
---------------X-X-----X-X---------------
----------------X-XXXXX-X----------------
----------------XX-----XX----------------
------------------XXXXX------------------
-----------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Nvm I did a wrong indent
this worked:

```
def makeOutline(lines):
    delList = []
    for i in range(len(lines)-1):

        for j in range(len(lines)-1):
            if lines[i][j] == "X" and lines[i+1][j] != "-" and lines[i-1][j] != "-" and lines[i][j+1] != "-" and lines[i][j-1] != "-":
                delList.append((i,j))
    for elm in delList:
        i = elm[0]
        j = elm[1]
        lines[i]= lines[i][:j] + "-" + lines[i][j+1:]
```